# Debug Spring boot code from command prompt

Tags: java, spring, debugging, spring-boot

Can I debug spring boot code through Spring tool suite(STS), if I it is running from command prompt?

It will help me in fast development.

Comment: What prevents you from doing it? What do you expect us to answer on such input?

Comment: either YES or NO that is sufficient for me sir :) was curious so that asked.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask curiosity-type questions unless you're willing to put some effort into research first.  What do you even mean by "debug ... if it is running from the command line"?  If you have remote debug enabled you can connect to it from your IDE just like you'd debug a remote JVM.  But you could have tried this yourself and actually learned how to do it.

Comment: Hey Jim, I did research but not able to find the exact link from where I should start that is why asked on StackOverflow, StackOverflow is always my last option if I stuck at somewhere, May be my question is basic but I am not aware of it. Thank you for your response got a link about remote debugging will do research on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line in Catalina.bat present in your tomcat/bin folder:

CATALINA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"

To debug from Eclipse:

run->Debug configurations...->Remote Java Application->New
Give port : 8000
host : localhost

and specify a name, the project you are debugging, and the tomcat host and debug port specified above. This will do your work